# Language selector Drupal 8

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I can't seem to get a Language Selector to appear on my page.html.twig (or in a block). I must be doing something wrong, I can perfectly translate my content by I can't switch language (unless I change the URL myself).

Comment: Add some code bits please?

Comment: I just couldn't find any blocks but I looked in the wrong place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide shows how to create a multi-lingual content.

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/d8-multi-lingual/

If not success please post some code you're trying to do. Remember to clear the cache.

Comment: Wow... I just had to press the "place block" and the Language Switcher block was there. Guess I'm still used to D7. Thanks.